# Force asset re-caching

Tags: bigcommerce

Cornerstone's carousel didn't work for my client's design, and so I built a custom hero component that I've included on several custom page templates. To allow the client to manually update images, I've set the hero images to use the `{{cdn}}` handlebars helper to pull images down from WebDAV.

E.g. `background-image: url('{{cdn "webdav:img/home-hero.jpg"}}');`

The issue we're running into now, is that, because the CDN caches asset files for the site on the server, when my client updates `home-hero.jpg` through WebDAV, the server has no way of knowing, and so it continues to serve the old version of `home-hero.jpg`.

Is there a way for my client to force re-caching of assets, or to bypass it altogether? I've attempted to use the `imbypass` parameter (`webdav:img/home-hero.jpg?imgbypass=on`), but this apparently just serves the unoptimized, but already cached, image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to append a random query string to the image src URL to prevent caching. If you're developing on a Stencil theme, the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use the {{moment}} helper to generate a date string so you can be sure you're getting a unique value each time.

```
<img src="/content/home-hero.jpg?{{moment}}"/>
```

will render as:

```
<img src="/content/home-hero.jpg?2018-08-23T00:00:00-05:00">
```

More info on using query strings to prevent caching: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Comment: Brilliant! I would still love for BC to introduce a way to manually clear the cache, but this works great for now.